# I can't remove the margin between two input fields

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove the margin between the search bar and the "Go!" button at the top of this page: http://beta.linksku.com/

I've tried removing all styles and adding `margin:0;padding:0;border:none;`, but there is still a margin between the two elements. I cannot replicate this problem on JSFiddle, but it occurs in all browsers on my website.

Comment: What's the problem? You want to move the Go button and the input field closer together?

Comment: What happens if you put something like a negative margin (e.g. `margin-left: -5px`) on the "Go!" button?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is how elements function as `inline-block`.

Normally when you use `inline-block` elements, you often use them inside a paragraph, so the space between the letters must be consistent. `inline-block` elements apply to this rule too.

If you want to remove the space completely, you *can* float the elements.

```
float: left;
```

You can also remove the whitespace from your template document. Like so:

```
<input type="text" name="s" tabindex="2" /><input type="submit" value="Go!" class="btn" />
```

Comment: You can set font-size to 0: no need to float!

Comment: You sure can! I do find float a more reasonable way to get around this. I should probably remove the 'have to' part :)

Comment: @primatology setting the font size to 0?!?! Where did you learn that? `float`ing is the best answer in this scenario, as the OP wants to move the elements out of normal flow to have more control over positioning ...

Comment: Setting the font size is like settings the letter-spacing to -4px imo. The spacing may change in different browsers.

Comment: @Xander, agreed this is a valid solution. But `float` was intended for flowing text around embedded content (ie, images in a paragraph), so it's no more the right tool for the job than the font-sizes trick.

Comment: @martinjlowm, there's no way to misinterpret zero font-size, though. Spaces might be five pixels or ten pixels, but a font-size of zero will always have no width. Anyway, this works :) upvoted!

Comment: Not sure why removing whitespace works, can someone explain?

Answer (score 10):

The space you're seeing is the default padding applied to inline elements. Simplest hack? Set `font-size: 0` on the `form`, then reset the actual font-size on the input and button.

Magic.

```
form {
    font-size: 0;
}

form input {
    font-size: 12px;
```

Why does this occur? The browser interprets the whitespace between the `input`s as a textual space, and renders accordingly. You can also smush all your elements together on one line, but that's ugly code soup.

Comment: @Xander, I disagree. The width of a space is not consistent between browsers :(

Comment: granted, though this solution requires more keystrokes and can become a pain to maintain if implemented in multiple areas ...

Answer (score 2):

That whitespace is relative to your font-size. You can remove it by adding `font-size:0` on the container of your inputs, in this case a form, like so:

```
form {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using chrome on the Mac, I can get rid of the space if I  edit the form node as HTML in the Developer tools, and remove the space between the two closing tags so:

```
<form id="search" method="get" action="http://beta.linksku.com/">
        <input type="text" name="s" tabindex="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Go!" class="btn">
      </form>
```

becomes:

```
<form id="search" method="get" action="http://beta.linksku.com/">
        <input type="text" name="s" tabindex="2"><input type="submit" value="Go!" class="btn">
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to remove space, but if you're not willing to have an unreadable one-line mess, you can use HTML comment:

```
<form id="search" method="get" action="http://beta.linksku.com/">
      <input type="text" name="s" tabindex="2"><!--
  !--><input type="submit" value="Go!" class="btn">
</form>
```