# Unwanted padding in table cell

Tags: textbox, html-table, cell, padding

I have a web page that does not appear as it does in design view.  It adds padding around table cells with text boxes in, but nowhere else. I want it without the padding.

This is the html:

```
<asp:Panel ID="PlayerPanel" runat="server" BackColor="#3333CC">
<table id="PlayerTable" style="width:100%;" border="0">
<tr>
<td >Name</td>
<td><asp:textbox id="txtPlayerName" runat="server" Width="400px" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:textbox></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Mobile</td>
<td><asp:textbox id="txtPlayerMobile" runat="server" Width="400px" AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:textbox></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Email</td>
<td><asp:textbox id="txtPlayerEmail" runat="server" Width="400px" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:textbox></td>
</tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
```

In design, it appears without padding.  When running, it appears with padding above and below the textbox of about the same height as the textbox.

I have tried setting `"padding:0px;"`  for the panel, the table and the cell, but it still stays the same.  What else can I try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't remove the margin between two input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832754/i-cant-remove-the-margin-between-two-input-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's cellpadding directly on the table? [look here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellpadding.asp); try setting that to 0

Maybe it's the browser itself putting some default styling on it - in Chrome, open up inspector (`F12` or right click -> inspect element) and there you can see what's being applied to the element.

Comment: I have tried adding the cellpadding, but it is no better.  It renders the same in IE and Chrome.

Comment: I found this fix:

Comment: I found this fix:
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

I added this into the css and it fixed the problem.  It is one of those 'Well, duh!' solutions.

Comment: I see - generally you'd use a css normalizer to "reset" these default styles. Of course, this does add a bit of overhead - if you use a frontend framework like Bootstrap or Foundation - they already have this baked in! Bonus for LESS/SASS support, grid system, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found this fix:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I added this into the css and it fixed the problem.  It is one of those 'Well, duh!' solutions.