# How to set individual table cell padding?

Tags: html, html-table, padding, css-tables, cellpadding

I have made bars in a waterfall diagram that I want to be look like blocks on each other. They are inline-blocks programmatically set to a width and adjusted sideways by margin-left.

The javascript to set innerHTML is irrelevant in this case, but the minimal CSS and HTML I have experimented on is below. Run this fiddle to see how it looks like:

```css
      * { padding:0; margin:0; }
      
      div { display:inline-block; }

      table {
        width:100%;
        white-space:nowrap;
        cellpadding:0;
      }

      td { border:solid 1px black; }
            
      .bar{
        margin:0;
        border:solid 1px red;
        background:yellow;
      }

      .padOnlyThisCell{
        padding:20px;
      }

      .padNotThisCell{
        padding:0;
      }
```

```html
    <br>
    <table cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td class='padOnlyThisCell'>
          First column
        </td>
        <td class='padNotThisCell'>
          
          <div class='bar padNotThisCell' style='margin-left:30%; width:30%'><sub> &nbsp; Why does this bar have margin? </sub></div>

          <sup> &nbsp; Why does this cell have padding?</sup>
          
        </td>
    </table>
    <br>
```

There is an unwanted table cell padding despite `padding:0` everywhere but not in the cells of first column where padding is wanted.

What I want is a bar with upper and lower red border touching it's surrounding black border.

It's the same in both Chrome and Firefox: *The `padding` in the first `<td>` affects the other `<td>` in the `<tr>`*. Why? How to change this code to not have space above and under the bar without loosing the padding in first column?

Comment: `style='margin-left:30%;...`  ?!  =___=

Comment: Explanation added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inner-block is resized to fit it's content that should have the padding.

Change `padNotThisCell` on the bar to `padThisCell` and it will work:

```css
      * { padding:0; margin:0; }
      
      div { display:inline-block; }

      table {
        width:100%;
        white-space:nowrap;
        cellpadding:0;
      }

      td { border:solid 1px black; }
            
      .bar{
        margin:0;
        border:solid 1px red;
        background:yellow;
      }

      .padThisCell{
        padding:20px;
      }

      .padNotThisCell{
        padding:0;
      }
```

```html
    <br>
    <table cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td class='padThisCell'>
          First column
        </td>
        <td class='padNotThisCell' style='width:100%;'>
          
          <div class='bar padThisCell' style='margin-left:30%; width:30%'> Bar </div>

          
        </td>
    </table>
    <br>
```

Renamed `padOnlyThisCell` to `padThisCell` because they are now on two places. Naming in code affects thougt. Renaming often is a good programming habit.

**The padding of first `<td>` does not affect the padding in the other `<td>`**! To see that I got help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010778/985399):  *in Chrome, open up inspector (F12 or right click -> inspect element) and there you can see what's being applied to the element*.

What actually happens is that an `inline-block` has the ability to shrink the borders to fit its content despite any paddings or margins around. ***Adding the same padding inside the bar as in the first cell makes a perfect fit***.

To be more specific a `padding-top:20px` and `padding-bottom:20px` in the .bar-rule of css will do (because i'm not shure if the padding otherwise can bug with the width). Also added `style='width:100%;'` in the second cell to push the first cell to shrink.